# Median of discrete random variable that is concentrated at 2 points

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is my random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(X=0.5)=0.5, \mathbb{P}(X=1.5)=0.5$. Then would the median of this distribution be any number in $[0.5, 1.5)?$

What about the random variable $X^2$? Am I right in saying that $\mathbb{P}(X^2=0.5^2)=0.5^2,\mathbb{P}(X^2=0.5*1.5)=0.5,\mathbb{P}(X^2=1.5^2)=0.5^2$? If so, what will be the median for this distribution? Will it be undefined in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Median's definition is $$P(X \le m) \ge \frac12, P(X \ge m) \ge \frac12$$

You are right for the first quesiton.

For $X^2$, we have

$$P(X^2=0.5^2)=0.5, P(X^2=1.5^2)=0.5$$

Hence the median is any number in $[0.5^2, 1.5^2).$

Now, let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d, what about the median for $Z=XY$.

We have $P(Z=0.5^2)=0.5^2, P(Z=0.5\cdot 1.5) = 0.5, P(Z=1.5^2)=0.5^2$,

the median is $0.5\cdot 1.5=0.75$.